Saving map using Map_Saver at the end of launch file
In my class I have been given a launch file that launches RVIZ, Gazeboo, NAV2 etc. It is my task to launch a node that has my robot drive in a square that is 1m by 1m. As the robot is driving it is creating a map of the area. I had success when adding a node to run the CPP file that performs the action of driving the robot.
I am not allowed to use service calls in the CPP file to call map_saver after the robot has finished its square.
I have tried to create a node that calls the map_saver cli function to save my maps as an action, but it keeps failing.
Is there a good resource I can look at to figure out how to delay saving the map until the robot has finished its square, and the syntax that I need to create the node so that the file saves in a directory I choose?

In order to use the map_saver from another node, you have to use the map_saver_server, not the map_saver cli.
You can launch the map_saver_server in your launch file or through the command line like:
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_saver_server

Then make sure that it is in an active state. And from your other node, create a SaveMap request. At the end of the README in the nav2_map_server, you can see an example of this service request through the command line.
